# Using Xceed PropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, propertygrid, xceed

I am a beginner at C#/WPF and am trying to use the Xceed PropertyGrid. On their site they show an example:

```
 <xctk:PropertyGrid x:Name="_propertyGrid" Width="450" Margin="10"
                                 AutoGenerateProperties="False">
            <!-- Only the following properties will be displayed in the PropertyGrid -->
            <xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
                <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="FirstName" />
                <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="FavoriteColor" />
                <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="PetNames" />
            </xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
        </xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

Which I have plugged in to my xaml. I see the PropertyGrid View however I do not see any of the property definitions.  I feel like I must be missing something basic? Am I supposed to add anything to the code-behind?

Comment: Maybe remove this line AutoGenerateProperties="False"?

Comment: i've tried this already, no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/353017

Also, you can download the source on the Xceed website. This comes up with samples using propertygrid which helped me as well. The trick is assigning PropertyGrid's 'SelectedObject'.

Comment: Yes I downloaded the source but I don't see any samples?

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Samples can be found on github: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/tree/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.LiveExplorer/Samples/PropertyGrid