# The Extended WPF Toolkit: Show items in PropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I would like to show some items in a control like property control in visual studio when i searched on the internet I found the most powerful tool is : [PropertyGrid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home)  but when i try follow the instruction the control failed to show values at my side . let me show snippet of code :

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid 
    SelectedObject="{Binding Markets}"  AutoGenerateProperties="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="242" Width="319">
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
            <xctk:PropertyDefinition Name="Name" />

            </xctk:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

and Markets are List of Market and Market class contain property called Name

Answer (score 8):

As has been mentioned elsewhere ([Using Xceed PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251890/using-xceed-propertygrid/10270756#10270756)) the trick is to set the SelectedObject.  It confused me at first too as many of the example do not include that property and searching didn't turn up solutions like the one linked above.